# How to decrease the search time in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, winforms

I have created a windows form that uses SQL Server Database. The windows form contains a search grid which brings all the bank account information of a person. The search grid contains a special field "Number of Account" which displays the number of Accounts a person have associated with a bank.

There are more than 100,000 records in the table from where the data is fetched. I just wanted to know how should I decrease the response time or the search time while getting the data from the table in the search grid.

When I run the page it takes hell lot of time to get the records displayed in the search grid. Moreover, it does not get the data unless and until I provide a search criteria(To and from Date for searching)

Is their any possible way to decrease the search time so that the data should get displayed in the grid.

Comment: Add an index? Can you show the qyery that is executed? Can you provide the execution plan of the query?

Comment: The question is very broad - therefore, you get a very broad answer: try to select **as few rows and columns** as possible, and make sure you have the right indexes in place. With this, you should have no problem fetching the data you need quickly.

Comment: For us to provide even remotely useful hints, you need to (1) show us the table structure and (2) the query you're using. At least these two things - otherwise, no useful answers are to be expected ....

Comment: If the grid already has data filters implemented, apart from what's been suggested, ensure the default range for these filters is set to a range that's not overly broad if you know your users will most likely not need the full historic data anyway. (i.e. last three onths instead of last 5 years).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that you can do:

1. Only fetch the minimum amount of data that you need for your results - this means only select the needed columns and limit the number of rows.
2. In addition to the above, consider using paging on the UI, so you can further limit the amount of data returned. There is no point in showing a user 100,000 rows.
3. If you hadn't done so already, add indexes to the table (though at 100,000 rows, things shouldn't be that slow anyway). I can't go into detail about how to do that.

Comment: well its not about showing 100,000 rows. the data that is fetched from the table and making the search grid slow is the column "Number of Account" which displays the number of account a person has. It make the search from the table containing 100,000 records. This is making the increase in response time

Comment: @Yash - All my points are still valid ways to help with speeding up responses.

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you for your help. I will try to make use of the points you suggested